# Program can't find my script files located

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

I am using node.js with express and Angularjs to build my site web,
but i'm getting the following output in the console
It seems like the program can't find my script files located

```
GET http://localhost:3000/images/entet_gauche.gif 404 (Not Found)
GET http://localhost:3000/js/app.js 
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.8/$injector/modulerr?p0=MetaStore&p1=Error%…ogleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.8%2Fangular.min.js%3A17%3A350)
```

It seems like the program can't find my script files located 
What is wrong with the path?

index.html

```
<body ng-app="MetaStore">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
    <img alt="Brand" src="./images/entet_gauche.gif">
  </a>

  <div ng-controller="produContr" class="container">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">

        <div ng-repeat="product in products | filter:search:strict" class="col-sm-3">
          <h3> {{product.name}} </h3>
          <p> {{product.content}} </p>
          <p><strong>Prix : </strong> {{product.prix}} DH</p>
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <script src="/js/app.js"></script>

</body>
```

js/app.js

var app = angular.module('MetaStore', []);
app.controller('produContr', function($scope, $http, $interval) {

})

server.js

```
var express = require("express");
var mysql = require("mysql");
var app = express();

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "root",
  password: "",
  database: "angularjsDB"
});

connection.connect(function(error) {
  if (error) {
    console.log("Problem with MySQL" + error);
  } else {
    console.log("Connected with Database");
  }
});

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

app.get('/load', function(req, res) {
  connection.query("SELECT * from product", function(err, rows) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("Problem with MySQL" + err);
    } else {
      res.end(JSON.stringify(rows));
    }
  });
});

app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log("It's Started on PORT 3000");
});
```

update : 
this is my directory structure :

```
index  location -> (folder/index.html) ...
server location -> (folder/server.js) ...
app location -> (folder/js/app.js) ...
picture location ->(folder/images/entet_gauche.gif)
```

Thanks for your attention and for taking a look

Comment: Try `src="images/entet_gauche.gif"` and `src="//images/entet_gauche.gif"`. Just out of curiosity!

Comment: can you post what your directory structure looks like?

Comment: Try adding `<base href="/"></base>` within your `head` tag, and replace the paths with `src="images/entet_gauche.gif"` and `src="js/app.js"`. Im assuming the paths are correct and the files are there!

Comment: It also does't work . this is my directory structure :
(folder/index.html)
...(folder/server.js)
...(folder/js/app.js)
...(folder/images/entet_gauche.gif)

Comment: Please try what Paul suggested below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you've not setup the static file middleware. Before you do routes, add:

`app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));`

Where 'public' is the folder with your CSS and js files. Check the express docs for other options you might want.

Comment: guessing in this case it would be app.use(express.static('js')) in his example?

Comment: Not necessarily, the default setup for most express apps is to have a public folder with a js folder inside that. In that setup, with my example code, the URL path to the js folder would be "/js", because the static middleware mounts the indicated folder on the root URL unless otherwise configured.

Comment: app.use("/images", express.static(__dirname + '/images'));
app.use("/js", express.static(__dirname + '/js'));

Comment: You shouldn't have to do it for each like that.  If you group all your static files in one directory (as mentioned in my previous comment) then you can do all of them in one assignment; they'll just be relative to the assigned folder.  So put the /images and /js folders inside a /public folder, then just `app.use(express.static(__dirname+'/public'));` and you should be good to go.